Managing Multiple solver Versions with Pyomo
I'm using Python 3.12.3 and Pyomo 6.7.0, and I use VSCode as my code editor. I have already connected GAMS 25.1 to Python. Now, I want to add GAMS 24.1 to Python. Here are my questions:
Would adding GAMS 24.1 cause neither GAMS 25.1 nor GAMS 24.1 to work properly?
How can I choose which version of GAMS, Pyomo should use?
What about other solvers like CPLEX?
Regards,
sreach on internet but i couldnt find anything
